# How to remove a column in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Imagine we have a 5x4 matrix. 
We need to remove only the first dimension. 
How can we do it with **numpy**?

```
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
       [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  15.],
       [ 16.,  17.,  18.,  19.]], dtype=float32)
```

I tried:

```
arr = np.arange(20, dtype=np.float32)
matrix = arr.reshape(5, 4)
new_arr = numpy.delete(matrix, matrix[:,0])
trimmed_matrix = new_arr.reshape(5, 3)
```

It looks a bit clunky. 
Am I doing it correctly?
If yes, is there a cleaner way to remove the dimension without reshaping?

Comment: You want to end up with a `(5, 3)` array?  Then you want to delete a column (or in general, an 'entry' from a dimension).  Removing a dimension would be changing to a `(5,)` or a `(4,)` array.

Comment: It seems you want to remove the first **column** from a 2D **array**. This can be done like this: `arr[:,1:]`.

Comment: `np.delete` works by index, not value.  It is not `list` `remove`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you want to remove a column from a 2D Numpy array you can specify the columns like this

to keep all rows and to get rid of column 0  (or start at column 1 through the end)

```
a[:,1:]
```

another way you can specify the columns you want to keep ( and change the order if you wish)
This keeps all rows and only uses columns 0,2,3

```
a[:,[0,2,3]]
```

The documentation on this can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html)

And if you want something which specifically removes columns you can do something like this:

```
idxs = list.range(4)
idxs.pop(2) #this removes elements from the list
a[:, idxs]
```

and @hpaulj brought up numpy.delete()

This would be how to return a view of 'a' with 2 columns removed (0 and 2) along axis=1.

```
np.delete(a,[0,2],1)
```

This doesn't actually remove the items from 'a',  it's return value is a new numpy array.

Comment: Only `[:,1:]` returns a `view` (i.e. uses the same data buffer).  The others make a copy.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to use `delete` is to specify index and dimension, eg. remove the 1st (0) column (dimension 1):

```
In [215]: np.delete(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4),0,1)
Out[215]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [17, 18, 19]])
```

other expressions that work:

```
np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)[:,1:]
np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)[:,[1,2,3]]
np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)[:,np.array([False,True,True,True])]
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the second reshape.

```
matrix=np.delete(matrix,0,1)
```