# numpy.delete not removing column from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.6

I'm attempting to remove each column one at a time from an array and, based on the documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632568/remove-a-specific-column-in-numpy), thought the following should work:

```
print(all_input_data.shape)

for n in range(9):
    print(n)
    testArray = all_input_data.copy()
    print(testArray.shape)
    np.delete(testArray,[n],axis=1)
    print(testArray.shape)
    print(testArray[0:1][:])
```

The original matrix is all_input_data.

This is not causing any columns to be deleted or generating any other change to the array. The initial output for the snippet above is:

```
(682120, 9)

0

(682120, 9)

(682120, 9)

[[  2.37000000e+02   1.60000000e+01   9.90000000e+01   1.04910000e+03
    9.29000000e-01   9.86000000e-01   8.43000000e-01   4.99290000e+01
    1.97000000e+00]]
```

The delete command is not changing the shape of the matrix at all.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) `numpy.delete` returns a _copy_ with the specified column(s) deleted. Also note that `n` will be invalid for `n >= 5` as you delete successively columns from the array. You should rather apply a `while` loop and always delete the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) returns a copy of the input array with elements removed.

> Return **a new array** with sub-arrays along an axis deleted.

There is no in place deletion of array elements in numpy.

Because `np.delete` returns a copy and does not modify the input there is no need to manually make a copy of `all_input_data`:

```
import numpy as np
all_input_data = np.random.rand(100, 9)

for n in range(9):
    print(n)
    testArray = np.delete(all_input_data,[n],axis=1)
    print(testArray.shape)
    print(testArray[0:1][:])
```

Comment: @a_guest I think you are wrong mainly for one reason: `all_input_data` is never modified. The rest follows from that.

Comment: @a_guets You are wrong again. The array is different in each iteration. Maybe you should try to run the code before commenting. As I understood the question, the OP wants to delete columns **one at a time**, not successively.

Comment: The original array is copied in every loop iteration, which strongly suggests an intent not to modify the array. But it's pretty useless to speculate on one's intent. Sooner or later the OP may clarify this point.

Comment: Deleted comments make me look like talking to myself :)

Comment: Thanks. You are correct in interpreting my intent, both in terms of the language used and the code.

Answer (score 1):

From linked question consider this:

```
In [2]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [3]: np.delete(a, [1,3], axis=1)
Out[3]:
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]])

In [4]: a
Out[4]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

In other words, if you want to save changes you should save to a new variable, but considering the size of your matrix this wouldn't be practical. What you could do is use <s>slice notation</s> indexing. It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007632/how-to-remove-a-column-in-a-numpy-array).

Comment: Using slice notation (actually indexing) to remove individual columns requires [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) which also copies the array just like `delete`.